# passing parameters to report in vb.net

Tags: parameters, report

I have created a report using report wizard in vb.net and have created a dataset with a parameter param. but when i pass the parameter parm it shows error message "An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'param' that is not defined in this report." plz help me to solve this problem i have tried the following code 
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms

```
Partial Class Default3
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim p As ReportParameter
        p = New ReportParameter("param", TextBox1.Text)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(p)
        ReportViewer1.DataBind()
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Your report, the one you created with the wizard, needs to have a parameter with the same name to receive the parameter value you're passing.  Since you said you created it with a parameter, perhaps the parameter name is something other than "param", such as "param1"?

Next, has the `LocalReport` property been set to the report you created?

Comment: Ann L i have checked it is param not any other name

Comment: @user3306226 OK, has the `LocalReport` property of the ReportViewer web control been set to point to your report?  You'd have to set that before setting the parameter in code, or it wouldn't know what parameters your report is supposed to have.